# Batchable start() method blows up Heap. How can this happen?

Tags: batch, heap

Production batchable blew up Heap in the `start()` method. Had been working OK before.

`start()`, unlike typical use cases that use `Database.QueryLocator` used an `Iterable`.

Code is shown below, designed to generate a bunch of ApexTypes `Foo` that get fed into `execute()`:

```
public class FooBatchable implements Database.Stateful, Database.Batchable<Foo> {
  public class FooIterable implements Iterable<Foo> {
    FoosService.BulkCreateParameters bulkParams;  
    public FooIterable(FoosService.BulkCreateParameters bulkParams) {
        this.bulkParams = bulkParams;
    }
    public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
        return new FooIterator(this.bulkParams);
    }
  }

  public class FooIterator implements Iterator<Foo> {
    Integer countToDate = 0; // # iterated so far through the iterable

    FoosService.BulkCreateParameters bulkParams; // Guidance for iterable result

    public FooIterator(FoosService.BulkCreateParameters bulkParams) {
        this.bulkParams = bulkParams;
    }
    public Boolean hasNext() {
        return countToDate < this.bulkParams.bulkCount;
    }

    //  generate the next Foo object 
    public Foo next() {
        Foo f = ... // use some Json magic
        this.countToDate++;
        Log.message(Json.serializePretty(f));
        return f;
    }
  } 

  public Iterable<Foo> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return new FooIterable(this.bulkParams);
  }

  ... execute and finish not shown, not important
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit was the innocent looking line:

```
Log.message(Json.serializePretty(f));
```

The Log class comes from Andrew Fawcett's [GitHub library Advanced Logging Patterns with Platform Events](https://github.com/afawcett/eventlogging). The `Log.message()` logs text to a static collection that ultimately, in a `Log.emit()` is published as a Platform Event.

But the real root cause is that `start()` is its own transaction in Salesforce and hence is governed by limits like any other transaction. If you are using Database.QueryLocator, SFDC internals manipulate query cursors and basically keep you from blowing up Heap in `start()`. But `Iterables` are another matter as you have complete control over how you decide when the # of objects to present to `execute()` ends.  Your `start()` code will show debug entries for the iterable/iterator across all `execute()`s.

Thus, for large jobs, adding into a static collection or a collection local to the Iterable or Iterator class (like `Log.message(xxx)`) will cause you to run out of heap.

In my specific use case, since I was never persisting to Platform Events via `Log.emit()`, using `Log.message()` was "dumb" and if I really needed some debugging info, I could have stuck with `System.debug(...)`